# Sharepoint C# - How to Download a File from GetFileByServerRelativeUrl

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I've tried pretty much every code sample and technique recommended on the first few pages of Google. All of these samples fail though with a timeout or similar error.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain") })
        {
            var tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
            String url = "https://sharepoint.organisation.net/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl/folder/file.docx')/$value')/Files";
            client.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), tmpFile);

            //OR 

            //              client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), tmpFile);
        }
    }
```

If anyone could give me a suggestion on why my code, regardless of method used to download, keeps timing out on the actual request, that would be great.

This method is to test file analysis on sharepoint.

Comment: That's not a valid url and there's no `GetServerByRelativeUrl` function. I think you want something like `https://sharepoint.organisation.net/_api/web/folders/getbyserverrelativeurl('folder')/files/getbyname('file.docx')/$value`

Comment: Sorry the method i'm actually using is GetFileByServerRelativeUrl

Comment: And the URL works otherwise, but is truncated to avoid revealing information about internal networks #operationalsecurity

Comment: The file  data comes from the `$value` endpoint. If the actual URL is well-formed (unlike your question's), it will work by ending the url at the `$value`

Comment: The full url works, when called and authenticated via a python script. Or accessed directly through an authenticated browser session.